# How to connect a display with MIPI DSI connector X to a board with connector Y?

Tags: connector, lcd, display, fcc

I want to connect a touchscren display to a development board via MIPI DSI interface, but their connectors do not match.

The **display** uses a **30-pin FCC, 1mm pitch**, double-side contacts connector ([link to connector](https://www.adafruit.com/product/4728), [link to the display](https://www.waveshare.com/4.3inch-DSI-LCD.htm))
The **board** has a **30-pin 5857 series, 0.35mm pitch**, connector ([link](https://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Kyocera-Electronic-Components/245857030201829%2b?qs=DPoM0jnrROXNJPAFB%2FcCKA%3D%3D))
It's a custom development board for which I do not have good documentation, but I do have the connector type, pinout and they say the board supports a single "4-lane DSI D-PHY, 1.2" interface for displays.

How can I connect the two?

Comment: Have you verifed if they are compatible, and you just need an electromechanical adapter to make the connections?

Comment: The display connector only uses certain pins (2-lane MIPI DSI + touchscreen I2C), while the board connector supports 4-lane MIPI DSI + power + backlight control pins etc.
It's the board connector that I am unfamilliar with, used in smartphones afaik, but not sure if it's possible to interface the display above with it (without custom PCB/FPC/adapter)

Comment: Funny thing is, if you don't give any info which products you are connecting together, how could we possibly know if they can be connected together at all? At least edit in the information you know about the devices, such as make, model, datasheet, manual, pinouts, etc.

Comment: It's a custom-made development board with lots of bells and whistles and I do not have much information about it myself (most of it is confidential, anyways).
However the board supports 4-lane DSI D-PHY, 1.2 and comes with the connector mentioned above. I have the pinout and it's not pin-to-pin compatible with my display.
The display however is [this one](https://www.waveshare.com/4.3inch-DSI-LCD.htm)  
What kind of information do I need to obtain in order to understand how to connect the two? (Thanks for your help btw)